# CD burn error message

Tags: 11.10, brasero, k3b

I'm using Oneiric and i can't burn CDs and DVDs on my system. I used Brasero and K3b and none would work, it would show an error every time somewhere near the 70% mark and the error would be something like it can't access cdrom or something. Try to fix it through some instructions on the forums but it wouldn't work still.

Any help?

I'm running 11.10 on a 64bit machine.

Thank y'all in advance guys!

Comment: With out knowing the exact error messages it will be very hard to help you out here. Please investigate and add more information the your question. Add also any steps you already took to solve this.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try burning the CD at a slower (preferable the slowest) speed. That often prevents burn failures, as well as reducing the frequency of corrupted burns that appear fine until you try to use them.

### Adjusting Burn Speed in Brasero

In Brasero, you can adjust the burning speed by clicking **Properties** in the *Image Burning Setup* window (i.e., in the window that comes up *right* before the burn).

You can select a slower speed in the **Burning speed** drop down menu, near the top of the Preferences dialog.

[image: adjusting burn speed in Brasero]

You won't necessarily have the same options shown there, as this depends in part on your CD/DVD burner.

### Adjusting Burn Speed in K3b

In K3b, you can adjust the burn speed in the same window where you tell it what image to burn.

[image: adjusting burn speed in K3b]

*Without more details in the question, this is likely the most effective solution that can be suggested for burns that fail to complete or are corrupted. It's often especially useful to reduce burn speed if you are at all unsure about the physical media to which you're burning, or if if you are burning a file containing data that will use most of its value if slightly corrupted (like computer programs, or an operating system).*

Answer (score 0):

Try ImgBurn in Wine, it works very well. Otherwise look for Nero 4 for Linux